# Inverse of Positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Assume $P$ is a non-negative positive definite matrix. It is well known what $P^{-1}$ is also positive definite and thus all its diagonal entries are positive. Can we say something about the off diagonal entries of $P^{-1}$? In particular can we say that $$P_{ij}>0 \implies P^{-1}_{ij}<0,\space  \forall i\neq j$$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a random counterexample to your conjecture:
$$
C=\pmatrix{4&4&4\\ 4&8&1\\ 4&1&8},\ \det(C)=28,
\ C^{-1}=\frac{1}{28}\pmatrix{63&-28&-28\\ -28&16&12\\ -28&12&16}.
$$
One can easily check that $C\succ0$ using Sylvester's criterion.

For those entrywise positive $P$s that satisfy your conjecture, $P^{-1}$ belongs to the class of [$M$-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason I made this conjecture is because I observed this in the positive definite matrices defined like this problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567507/do-these-matrices-have-any-name (I could not prove it yet)